# Kendo Multiselect with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I want to set maxSelectedItems from a textbox value. Apart from that I want to reset kendo multiselect if textbox value change. I have tried below thing but it is not working.

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="DTO.ProgramID" id="ProgramID" value="3">

<input class="form-control" data-val="true" id="ClassSize " maxlength="2" name="ClassSize " ng-model="DTO.ClassSize "type="text" ng-blur="OnClassSizeChange()">

<select id="CourseClientIDs" kendo-multi-select k-options="selectClientOptions" ng-model="DTO.CourseClientIDs"></select>

$scope.selectClientOptions = {
    placeholder: "---Select Clients---",
    dataTextField: "ClientFLName",
    dataValueField: "ClientID",
    valuePrimitive: true,
    autoBind: false,
    dataSource: {
        type: "jsonp",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "Home/ClientDataSource/",
                cache: false
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, action) {
                if (action === "read") {
                    if ($scope.DTO.ProgramID != undefined) {
                        return {
                            programID: $scope.DTO.ProgramID
                        };
                    }
                } else {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

$scope.OnClassSizeChange = function () {
    if ($scope.DTO.ClassSize == 0) {
        var message = "Class size cannot be 0.";
        return false;
    }else{
       $scope.selectClientOptions.maxSelectedItems = $scope.DTO.ClassSize; //Not Working
       $scope.selectClientOptions.dataSource.read(); //Not Working
    }
    return true;
};
```

I am trying angularjs with kendo first time. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the textbox define ngChange specify the function to execute when value change. Supposing ngModel for textbox is in $scope.nvm, try this:

```
            $scope.nvm = 1; //value in textfield
            $scope.setnvm = function(){//change maxSelectedItems and reset values
                var ms = angular.element(document.getElementById("sems")).data("kendoMultiSelect");
                ms.setOptions({
                    maxSelectedItems: $scope.nvm,
                });
                ms.value([]);
            };
```